# SQLAlchemy GUID Custom Type or SQLAlchemy-Utils UUID Type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

While researching ways to implement UUID/GUID for table ID obfuscation, I've come across two methods of accomplishing this task but I'm having trouble differentiating between the two.

The SQLAlchemy-Utils version, [sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid.UUIDType](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid), seems to do a bit more than the alternative, but I can't tell what, exactly. I feel it's also nice to use a library if its available to get things right.

On the other hand, SQLAlchemy has a specific section for implementing a [Backend-agnostic GUID Type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type) which seems more succinct and accomplishes the same task with similar dialect fallbacks and options for CHAR and BINARY storage.

So I'm at a crossroads and simply lack sufficient knowledge to choose the right path. My implementation would be with Flask-Sqlalchemy and MySQL.

What is the real-world difference of these two implementations, aside from their name?

I suppose my last option would be to simply migrate to PostgreSQL and sidestep this entire boondoggle.

What would you do?

Comment: Can't help with the specific differences, but I can say what I did. I noticed those two approaches as well, but went with the sqlalchemy_utils version as I use it for UUIDs and a few other field types. It's worked great for me.

Comment: I also went with SQLAlchemy Utils UUID, and I've been very happy.